# $A^TA=B^TB$ implies $\exists P \in M_{m\times m}(\Bbb{R})$. such that $A=PB$,where $P$ is an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume $A,B \in M_{n\times m}(\Bbb{R})$,and $A^TA=B^TB$,show that there exists an orthogonal matrix $P$, such that $A=PB$.

Comment: could you please share your ideas...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik .up to now, I have no idea. Only know $A^TA$ can be diagonalization.

Comment: do you mean $A^T A$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik. yes. diagonalizable. thank you.

Comment: not much information but as you said $A^TA$ is diagonalizable, you can say $A,B$ are actually square matrices

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik. yes,thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the condition implies $\langle x, A^TAy \rangle = \langle Ax, Ay \rangle = \langle x, B^TBy \rangle = \langle Bx, By \rangle$ for all $x,y$. Letting $x=y$ shows that $\|Ax\| = \|Bx\|$, hence we have $\ker A = \ker B$.

Let $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_r$ be an orthonormal basis for $ {\cal R} A$. Now choose  $v_i \in (\ker A)^\bot$ such that $A v_i = \alpha_i$.

Define $\beta_i = B v_i$. I claim that the $\beta_i $ form an orthonormal basis for ${\cal R} B$. The above shows that $ \langle Av_i, Av_j \rangle =  \langle Bv_i, Bv_j \rangle$, from which we get $ \langle \alpha_i, \alpha_j \rangle =  \langle \beta_i, \beta_j \rangle$, from which it follows that the $\beta_i $ are orthonormal.
Since $\ker A = \ker B$, we have $\dim {\cal R} A = \dim {\cal R} B$, from which it follows that the $\beta_i $ are orthonormal basis for ${\cal R} B$.

Now complete the respective bases so that $\alpha_1,...,,\alpha_n$ and $\beta_1,...,\beta_n$ form orthonormal bases for $\mathbb{R}^n$,
and define $P$ by $P \beta_i = \alpha_i$.

Then we have $\langle \alpha_i, \alpha_j \rangle = \langle P \beta_i, P \beta_j \rangle = \langle \beta_i, P^TP \beta_j \rangle = \langle \beta_i, \beta_j \rangle$, $i=1,...,n$. This shows
that $P^T Px = x$ for all $x$, hence we have $P^T P = I$.

Comment: Thanks very much.I am too stupid. I also have an doubt in the reply.  In order to show that $P^TPx=x$ for all $x\in \mathcal{R}B$, it is equivalent to $P^TPBv_j=Bv_j$ for $i=1,\cdots,r$, $\Longleftrightarrow$ $<(P^TP-I)Bv_i,(P^TP-I)Bv_i>=0$, and we have $<Bv_i,(P^TP-I)Bv_j>=0$ for $1\leq i,j\leq r$. so I need to show that $(P^TP-I)Bv_j \in \mathcal{R}B$ for $i=1,\cdots,r$. But I don't know how to do this.

Comment: $B v_j$ spans ${\cal R}B$, so if $P^TP Bv_j = Bv_j$ then $P^TP x = x$ for all $x \in {\cal R}B$. Thats it!

Comment: You must have $(P^TP-I) B = 0$.

Comment: thanks very much, but why $P^TPBv_j=Bv_j$? it is equivalent to $\langle (P^TP-I)Bv_j,(P^TP-I)Bv_j \rangle=0$. From $\langle Bv_i, P^TPBv_j \rangle = \langle Bv_i, Bv_j \rangle$, I know $\langle \sum_{k=1}^{r} a_kBv_k, (P^TP-I)Bv_j\rangle = 0$. If $(P^TP-I)Bv_j \in \mathcal{R}B$,we can find $a_k$, such that $\sum a_kBv_k = (P^TP-I)Bv_j$. I don't know how to do show that $(P^TP-I)Bv_j \in \mathcal{R}B$.

Comment: I may have made a  mistake. Let me check. (I would delete my answer until I find a fix, but the system won't let me.)

Comment: Thanks very much. This post had been closed. so can't do some operation on it.

Comment: I think I have a fix. The idea is the same as above, but the bases need to be chosen much more carefully.

Comment: @Laura: Thanks for catching my sloppiness. I needed to choose the $v_i$ much more carefully.

Comment: Thanks very much. I have understood. And in the third line. there maybe has a typo. $\dim \mathcal{R}A$. I think the key is there exist $v_i \in (\ker A)^\bot$ such that $Av_i$ and $Bv_i$ are both orthonormal basis of $\mathcal{R}A$ and $\mathcal{R}B$.

Comment: @Laura: Fixed the typo!