# Can we show a matrix always exists to satisfy these properties

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Suppose there are two matrices A and B.
A has dimension $K \times D$ and B has dimension $D \times K$.

The two matrices obey the following relationships
$A = (B^T B) ^{-1} B^T$

$B = \Sigma A^T (A \Sigma A^T) ^{-1}$ where $\Sigma$ is a matrix that has dimension $D \times D$

And let us define the product $P= BA$ where $P$ has dimension $D \times D$.

I am interested in other pairs of matrices that also have a product equal to $P$.

A simple example would be to introduce an invertible matrix C with dimension $K \times K$. If I define new matrices $X=CA$ and $Y=BC^{-1}$ then it is clear that the product $YX$ will also be equal to $P$.

The question I want to answer is whether it is always possible to find a matrix $C$ such that $X$ and $Y$ will obey the following properties:

$Y^TY=\mathbb{1}$

$X=Y^T$

**My Attempt (probably wrong)**

I'm not really sure how to go about establishing this. My attempt so far has been to expand the two desired properties in terms of A, B, C which leads to

$\begin{align} Y^TY &= \mathbb{1} \\ (BC^{-1})^T BC^{-1} &= \mathbb{1} \\ (C^T) ^{-1} B^T BC^{-1} &= \mathbb{1} \\ B^TB &= C^TC \qquad \text{(1)} \end{align} $

and

$\begin{align} X &= Y^T \\ CA &= (BC^{-1})^T \qquad \text{(2)} \end{align} $

From (1) it is tempting to set C=B but this is not allowed because the dimensions don't match. Beyond that I haven't made any progress in using (1) and (2) to help establish I can always find such a C. I have however [read here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523262/ata-btb-implies-exists-p-in-m-m-times-m-bbbr-such-that-a-pb-whe) that (1) does mean there exists an orthogonal matrix O such that C=OB. Is this of any use?

I'd appreciate some help please!